# C# Service Client - Transfer-Encoding: Chunked

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, soap-client, webservice-client

I'm currently trying to fix my SOAP-Client in C#, but got somehow stuck with the Transfer-Encoding. I'm more or less a newbie to C#, so it's completly possible that im just missing something minor here.

I consumed a SOAP service from our local Tomcat Server following this: https://web.archive.org/web/20180506023052/http://www.csharptutorial.in/37/csharp-net-how-to-consume-a-web-service-in-csharp-net-visual-studio-2010

My current code:

```
using System;
using ConsoleApp1.Lims;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LimsZugriffService client = new LimsZugriffService();
           // FunktionsErgebnis response = client.connect();
           // Console.WriteLine("Connect" + response.meldung);
            String[] bond = new String[] { "versuch.auftrag.nr=2014/0031" };
            String[] bondFail = new String[] { "abc" };
            VersuchsschrittErgebnis reponseVersuch = client.ermittleVersuchsschritte(bond);
            Console.WriteLine(reponseVersuch.ermittelteVersuchsschritte.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(reponseVersuch.meldung);

        }
    }
}
```

After some testing I found out, that something does not work as intended. My Response-Array of `<ermittelteVersuchsschritte>` seems to be empty, while the "control"-Flags are parsed normally.

I captured the traffic between client and server to figure out what was wrong and it was actually completly there. Just chunked into 8192 Byte blocks.

Could it be, that the C# implementation of the WebClient got some problems with `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked`?

After googling for some hours i could not find a satisfiying solution to this issue. I hope somebody, who knows C# and WebServices better than me has the answer.

For the sake of completeness:

My [WSDL](https://gist.github.com/Pandastan/746a8a80bb6e8bfe7091062ce02ceb27)

My [Traffic - Request->Response](https://gist.github.com/Pandastan/931f50cfa753897a1398dfe8cff27405)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching, trial and error and much time I finally figured out my mistake.

C# seems **not** to have a problem with the `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked`

The mistake was on the service side. The consumed `wsdl` was generated from java code with the help of `Axis`(the first `Axis` not `Axis2`). Axis generated a `wsdl 1.0` while C# seems to expect `wsdl 2.0`. So in the end, the XML-structure described in the `wsdl` was flawed and could not be automatically consumed.

We fixed this problem by switching from `Axis` to `Apache CXF`. The newly generated `wsdl` was than consumed without a problem at our C# - client side.